# I am using a jquery type accordian with hidden text. All div classes open at the same time but I am only wanting 1 to open. to open at a time

Tags: jquery, hidden

i have text hidden in div classes that when you click read more, I would like the panel to toggle down. The problem is all panels with that class name open, I only want one you clicked to open

```
    <div class="earlyNews">
    <div class="layer">
    <div class="newsWrap">
    <div class="newsTitle">perfectly balanced</div>
    <img  class="newsImage" src="assets/images/240x160.jpg"  align="left"/>
    <div class="newsText">
    <p>Ous illa dolo inctem coria prempor posae. Exeri omnimus animusciatem   restium fuga. Nequi dolut idendi consequam id eatiis autaque nos volorporiunt quis re quid mos nulparibus ea volorio.Mossum sum fugia pore verum is erspidellit, solor aut accuptatium sum estistiis estminveliquis....</p> <span class="more">Read more</span>
    </div>

    </div><!-- newsWrap -->
    <div class="moreTextPanel "><p class="hell">blagh blash shfiohthioudlbe the rest of the text hereSed et lectus in massa imperdiet tincidunt. Praesent neque tortor, sollicitudin non, euismod a, adipiscing a, est. Mauris diam metus, varius nec, faucibus at, faucibus sollicitudin, lectus. Nam posuere felis ac urna. Vestibulum tempor vestibulum urna. Nullam metus. Vivamus ac purus. Nullam interdum ullamcorper libero. Morbi vehicula imperdiet justo. Etiam mollis fringilla ante. Donec et dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Etiam mi libero, luctus nec, blandit ac, rutrum ac, lectus.</p>
</div>

</div><!-- layer -->
</div><!-- earlyNews -->

    <div class="earlyNews" >
    <div class="layer">
    <div class="newsWrap">
    <div class="newsTitle">perfectly balanced</div>
    <a href="#"><img  class="newsImage" src="assets/images/240x160.jpg"  align="left"/></a>
    <div class="newsText">
    <p>dolo inctem coria prempor posae. Exeri omnimus animusciatem veris uissimoblandi omnim restium fuga. Nequi dolut idendi consequam id eatiis autaque nos volorporiunt quis re quid mos nulparibus ea volorio. </p> 
    <span class="more">Read more</span></div>

    </div><!-- newsWrap -->
    <div class="moreTextPanel">
    <p class="hell">this woudlbe the rest of the text here
    Sed et lectus in massa imperdiet tincidunt. Praesent neque tortor, sollicitudin non, euismod a, adipiscing a, est. Mauris diam metus, varius nec, faucibus at, faucibus sollicitudin, lectus. Nam posuere felis ac urna. Vestibulum tempor vestibulum urna. Nullam metus. Vivamus ac purus. Nullam interdum ullamcorper libero. Morbi vehicula imperdiet justo. Etiam mollis fringilla ante. Donec et dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Etiam mi libero, luctus nec, blandit ac, rutrum ac, lectus.</p>

    </div>

    </div><!-- layer -->
    </div><!-- earlyNews -->

    jquery 
      $(".more ").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".hell").slideToggle("slow");

        if($(this).text() == 'Close')
       {
          $(this).text('Read more');
     }
       else
   {
         $(this).text('Close');
    }
   });
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle of your code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mhtr5Lfx/

Comment: check this [https://jsfiddle.net/tanyasinha/mhtr5Lfx/1/

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked really well

Comment: i am glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".more ").click(function(){
   $(this).closest('.newsWrap').next().find('.hell').slideToggle("slow"); 
    if($(this).text() == 'Close')
     {
       $(this).text('Read more');
     }else
     { 
     $(this).text('Close');
     }
  });
});
```

```css
.hell{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="earlyNews">
<div class="layer">
<div class="newsWrap">
<div class="newsTitle">perfectly balanced</div>
<img  class="newsImage" src="assets/images/240x160.jpg"  align="left"/>
<div class="newsText">
<p>Ous illa dolo inctem coria prempor posae. Exeri omnimus animusciatem   restium fuga. Nequi dolut idendi consequam id eatiis autaque nos volorporiunt quis re quid mos nulparibus ea volorio.Mossum sum fugia pore verum is erspidellit, solor aut accuptatium sum estistiis estminveliquis....</p> 
<span class="more">Read more</span>
</div>
</div><!-- newsWrap -->
<div class="moreTextPanel ">
<p class="hell">blagh blash shfiohthioudlbe the rest of the text hereSed et lectus in massa imperdiet tincidunt. Praesent neque tortor, sollicitudin non, euismod a, adipiscing a, est. Mauris diam metus, varius nec, faucibus at, faucibus sollicitudin, lectus. Nam posuere felis ac urna. Vestibulum tempor vestibulum urna. Nullam metus. Vivamus ac purus. Nullam interdum ullamcorper libero. Morbi vehicula imperdiet justo. Etiam mollis fringilla ante. Donec et dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Etiam mi libero, luctus nec, blandit ac, rutrum ac, lectus.</p>
</div>
</div><!-- layer -->
</div><!-- earlyNews -->
<div class="earlyNews" >
<div class="layer">
<div class="newsWrap">
<div class="newsTitle">perfectly balanced</div>
<a href="#"><img  class="newsImage" src="assets/images/240x160.jpg"  align="left"/></a>
<div class="newsText">
<p>dolo inctem coria prempor posae. Exeri omnimus animusciatem veris uissimoblandi omnim restium fuga. Nequi dolut idendi consequam id eatiis autaque nos volorporiunt quis re quid mos nulparibus ea volorio. </p> 
<span class="more">Read more</span></div>
</div><!-- newsWrap -->
<div class="moreTextPanel">
<p class="hell">this woudlbe the rest of the text here
Sed et lectus in massa imperdiet tincidunt. Praesent neque tortor, sollicitudin non, euismod a, adipiscing a, est. Mauris diam metus, varius nec, faucibus at, faucibus sollicitudin, lectus. Nam posuere felis ac urna. Vestibulum tempor vestibulum urna. Nullam metus. Vivamus ac purus. Nullam interdum ullamcorper libero. Morbi vehicula imperdiet justo. Etiam mollis fringilla ante. Donec et dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Etiam mi libero, luctus nec, blandit ac, rutrum ac, lectus.</p>
</div>
</div><!-- layer -->
</div><!-- earlyNews -->
```